# jQuery // why is this if-statement incorrect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

In my html I have a div with 7 images listed but in the div "fit" only 5, so I created 2 buttons (bt1 and bt2) to "scroll horizontally" through these images.

What I want is when I click on bt2 AND the first image is on the first position  (in this case when left is 0px), the images shouldn't be able to scroll further, else they just scroll normally.

**Code snippet**

```
$("#bt2").click(function()
 {
    if (($("#symbole").find("img").first().css({"left:0px"}))==true)
          {         
          }
    else{
          $("img").animate({
          "left":"+=100px"
          },
        420);
    }
 });
```

Comment: `if(!parseInt($("#symbole img:first-child").css("left"),10))` You want to get the `left` value, but in your code, you are actually setting it to `0`.

Comment: It helps a lot if you put your brackets on the right lines and if you put spaces where they belong... ;-) Won't fix the issue but it will prevent you from making stupid mistakes an makes it more readable for others...

Answer (score 5):

The `css` method does not return boolean *true / false* so that you can compare it with true as you did. You need to get css value for left but you are setting it

```
if (($("#symbole").find("img").first().css("left") === "0px")
```

OR

```
if($("#symbole img:eq(0)").css("left") === "0px")
```

Answer (score 2):

or use parseInt in order to get the value without px

```
if (parseInt($("#symbole").find("img").first().css("left"), 10) === 0)
```

Updated with suggestions.

Comment: Please add the radix for older browsers. `parseInt(string, 10)`

Comment: good solution too but again avoid == and use === instead. Just make a habit out of it. falsy and truethy are tricky bastards :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are setting the css. You need to get the css attribute left and then compare it.

```
 if ($("#symbole").find("img").first().css("left") == "0px")
```

Answer (score 0):

Css does not return true/false.you need to compare it with value like:

```
if (($("#symbole").find("img").first().css("left") === "0px")
```

Try using this instead of your if.